# Event data not being populated dynamically in Fullcalendar 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, fullcalendar-4

I have a db which contains all the events for a month/period. I've used http.get and got the JSON file. This file has additional data which has to be modified or formatted before it can be used as an event. Eg: For event title: name +id .
So I've formatted it accordingly and storing it as a string in a local variable. I'm trying to assign this variable as event data. But this is not being populated.

I've already tried converting the string to Array,by using Array.to(var). The result is still the same. Ive also tried to store it in a uri and passing the same as event data, url: uri. This also failed to display the event.
Read in fullcalendar docs about addEvent method. But Im relatively new to Angular 8 so have no idea how to implement that.

So, rn theres no errors, but i seem to be missing the big picture. Ill put out all the things im doing.
Theres an interface evtdata:

```
export interface Evtdata {

  startRecur?: any,
  endRecur?: any,
  startTime?: any,
  endTime?: any,
  title?: any,
  daysOfWeek?: any

}
```

Updated Component:

```
this.options$ = this.evts.getEventDat().pipe(
      map(data => {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.data.length; i++) {
                this.eventdat[i].startRecur = "\""+data[i].startDate+"\"";
                this.eventdat[i].endRecur = "\""+data[i].endDate+"\"";
                this.eventdat[i].startTime ="\""+ data[i].startTime+"\"";
                this.eventdat[i].endTime = "\""+data[i].endTime+"\"";
                this.eventdat[i].title ="\""+ data[i].name + " " + data[i].wwid+" "+data[i].sId+"\"";
                this.eventdat[i].daysOfWeek ="\""+ "[" + data[i].workDays + "]"+"\"";
              }
            return {
             businessHours: {
                daysOfWeek: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
                startTime: '00:00',
                endTime: '24:00',
              },
              editable: true,
              customButtons: {
              },
              header: {
                left: 'prev,next',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'dayGridMonth,listView,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
              },
              plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, listPlugin, bootstrapPlugin, timeGrigPlugin],
              events: this.eventdat
            }

      })

    );
```

calendar.html

```
<full-calendar
 *ngIf="options$ | async"

  #fullcalendar
  themeSystem="bootstrap"
  [businessHours]="(options$ | async).businessHours"
  [editable]="true"
  [events]="(options$ | async).events"
  [header]="(options$ | async).header"
  [customButtons]="(options$ | async).customButtons"
  [plugins]="(options$ | async).plugins"
  (addEventSource)="addEventSource($event)"
  (eventClick)="eventClick($event)"
  (setProp)="setProp($event)"

></full-calendar>
```

Ive added multiple logs to display the data, data is getting saved and is being executed in the required order. Events are still not being populated.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of unnecessary code here. Firstly, you don't need async/await if you are adding a `.then` block. Secondly, it looks like you are trying to write JSON in a string format somehow...why are you trying to manipulate everything as a string? Why not simply manipulate it as an object? You can turn a JSON-formatted string into an object with `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: Async part was added because, before getting the data from response, it was executing the rest of the codes, so I had to make the rest of the code wait. And as far as I understand, I have to pass Array as event source. Im converting many to string cause I need it in that format as above. Do let me know if there is a better way to format json response

Comment: Either you put in an async/await, at which point you don't need a .then block, or you put a .then block, and anything that needs to happen after data has been received goes in that then block. It's best to avoid mixing the two. As for the rest…it's really not very clear what you want to do. Please include the format of what you are getting back from the server and what it needs to be transformed to.

Comment: Also, why are you using toPromise? Are you transforming the Observable exposed by the HttpClient?

Comment: JSON Response: ` Name: something, Id: Something, start: , End:  , start time: , End time: ` Im trying to change this into Event acceptable format: ` Title: contains name and id and starttime,endtime so on.` I am recieving the data right now, but unable to display the data in FullCalendar. Data doesnt seem to be the issue

Answer (score 0):

You're doing all kinds of manipulations of the data, few of which I really understand. If you're doing an HTTP call, it returns an Observable. You can then `pipe` in a `map` operator where you add/remove/modify anything you need to. You can then use the `async` pipe in the template to avoid all of the subscription problems.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.options = this.evts.getEventDat().pipe(
    map(data => {
      // format your options object here, using the data object as needed
      // don't forget that this map operator is NOT the same as Array map
      // you can of course do an Array map in here as well if you need to
    })
  );
}
```

Then, in the template:

```html
<full-calendar
  *ngIf="options | async"

  #fullcalendar
  themeSystem="bootstrap"
  [businessHours]="(options | async).businessHours"
  [editable]="true"
  [events]="(options | async).events"
  [header]="(options | async).header"
  [customButtons]="(options | async).customButtons"
  [plugins]="(options | async).plugins"
  (eventClick)="eventClick($event)"
  (setProp)="setProp($event)"


></full-calendar>
```

I still don't understand a lot of your formatting. It feels like you're trying to manipulate JSON as a string, which you don't need to do. You can manipulate it as an object, which is kinda the whole point.

P.S. If you need to go back and forth between JSON and string notation, use JSON.parse(myString) and JSON.stringify(myObject).

Comment: Will try this out and get back to you!

Comment: there seems to be an error while assigning this.options = ... line. 
Error is:Type 'Observable<void>' has no properties in common with type 'OptionsInput'.

Comment: You need to declare `this.options` as an `Observable<OptionsInput>`

Comment: Im relatively new to angular, Please do let me know if this is what im supposed to do: ```getEventDat():Observable<OptionsInput>{
    return this.http.get(this._url);
  }```

Comment: Your `getEventDat()` method does not return an Observable of type `OptionsInput`, so it doesn't need to be changed. It is the Observable `pipe` in your calendar component which does that. Remember, `this.options` will be an Observable of whatever type the end of the `pipe` spits out. In your calendar component, you set options: Observable<OptionsInput>, and make sure that your transformation creates a valid `OptionsInput` object. (I'd also recommend using `options$` as a variable name, as the norm is to add `$` on the end of Observable-like variable names).

Comment: Add a `tap(console.log)` after the `map` in your Observable pipe to check the shape of the data object being emitted to make sure you're emitting the right thing.

Comment: No error. Nothing in Browser console too. And calendar is not displayed now. Can you move this to chat? I dont have enough reputation to do it

Comment: For some reason it won't allow me to either…

Comment: Try adding the `tap` to check the data object you're emitting, and make sure everything is correct, i.e. it lines up with the shape of object the `full-calendar` component is expecting.